# Can I pull specific data from an unopened workbook, like a v-lookup using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, automation, vlookup

I currently have the below code for copying and pasting data from an unopen workbook's specific sheet (which works), however I now need to pull specific data from that sheet based on a specific variable (like a v-lookup). Is this possible using VBA and without opening the workbook?

```
Sub GetFileCopyData()
   Dim Fname As String
   Dim SrcWbk As Workbook
   Dim DestWbk As Workbook

   Set DestWbk = ThisWorkbook

   Fname = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xls*), *.xls*", Title:="Select a File")
   If Fname = "False" Then Exit Sub
   Set SrcWbk = Workbooks.Open(Fname)

   SrcWbk.Sheets("Projects Register").Range("A1:V500").Copy DestWbk.Sheets("ProjectsDelivery").Range("A2,V500")

   SrcWbk.Close False
End Sub
```

Comment: Define "without opening it". Through VBA you can hide the whole action of opening the workbook, extracting the data and closing it again, without it being visible to the user. Have you tried using Vlookup, and selecting the array directly in the other open book? or do you need to have it fully in VBA?

Comment: Yeah I mean hiding the action. the workbook I will be getting the data from changes weekly so by using the VBA above it allows me to select the file (workbook) I want to copy from.

Comment: Start your code with application.screenupdating=false

Comment: what about pulling data from workbook? I want to be able to pull a whole row based on an identifier which is projects 'On-hold', these will then be moved to a different workbook/sheet

Comment: Yes you can do that as well, but that is a different question. Look into `Entirerow` or `.row` operations :-)

Comment: that's not much help for what the original goal was...

Comment: If you're wanting to pull in data from an external workbook, why not use PowerQuery? Data > Get Data > From File > From Workbook.